# Using fscanf() to read file line by line including whitespaces

Tags: c, scanf, whitespace

I need to read a text file in c line by line using fscanf (yes I know, fgets() is better for this, but it is a contrived assignment). 
The data in the file is formatted as follows (ignoring quotes):

```
"firstname lastname"|100|500|300                                    
"otherfirstname otherlastname"|150|450|120
etc...
```

each point will be read like,  fscanf(fp, "%s|%d|%d|%d\n", buf, &int1, &int2, &int3);

The way above works, however, the string will only be read as the first word (firstname) and the second word will be left out. I have tried using [^\n] but I end up just infinitely printing the first line in the file.

What I want to know is the best way to loop through the file line by line using a statement similar to the above, that can read entire strings with spaces without ruining everything else.

Comment: It might be because you are not passing the address of int1, int2, int3 to fscanf, and thus, it is writting into who knows which part of memory which might be affecting the behaviour of the entire function.

Comment: If it is not the case and your fscanf example here is not the actual code you are working into, please, add the actual code that is misbehaving

Comment: The name ends at the first `|`,so you should be using `%[^|]` to read the name.

Comment: are quotes part of the format? If not, why do you add it and then, ask us to ignore them?

Answer (score 1):

Here you are. For simplicity there is used `sscanf` instead of `fscanf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char *buf = "firstname lastname|100|500|300 \n"
                      "otherfirstname otherlastname |150|450|120  \n";

    char name[100];
    int x, y, z;

    int offset = 0;
    while ( sscanf( buf, "%[^|] | %d | %d | %d%n", name, &x, &y, &z, &offset ) == 4 )
    {
        buf += offset;

        sscanf( buf, "%*[^\n]%n", &offset );
        buf += offset;
        sscanf( buf, "%*c%n", &offset );
        buf += offset;

        printf( "%s, %d, %d, %d\n", name, x, y, z );
    }       

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
firstname lastname, 100, 500, 300
otherfirstname otherlastname , 150, 450, 120
```

Comment: It would be safer to use `%99[^|]` to prevent overflow on long input.

Comment: You need to reset `offset = 0` before each sscanf call that doesn't check the return value to deal with match failure...

Comment: @ChrisDodd I showed a general approach. When used with files these is no need to use offset.